# Access denied for user ''@'localhost'. Trying to insert data PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, permissions, user-permissions

I'm trying to insert data into my database, but the error that I get is:
Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

The strange thing is that I can select data from my database and it also displays this data into my form fields.

http://sayhey.nl/mealapp/add-ingredients.php

But when I try to insert new data via this form, it gives the 'access denied' error. It looks like there is no username or password set, but actually I did do this:

```
//Connect to database
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "databasename";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

And this is the rest of the code:

```
<?php
//Connect
include 'connect.php';
$ingredient_sql = "SELECT id, name FROM ingredient_cat";
$ingredient_cat_result = $conn->query($ingredient_sql);
?>
<div id="wrapper">
    <form method = "post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
        <input name="ingredient_name" type="text" id="ingredient-name" />
        <select name="ingredient_cat" id="ingredient-cat">
            <?php
             while($row = $ingredient_cat_result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["name"].'</option>';                 
             }
            ?>
        </select>
        <select name="ingredient_unit" id="ingredient-unit">
            <option value="stuks">stuks</option>
            <option value="gram">gram</option>
            <option value="liter">liter</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add ingredient" />
    </form>
</div>  
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
    $ingredient_name = $_POST['ingredient_name'];
    $ingredient_cat = $_POST['ingredient_cat'];
    $ingredient_unit = $_POST['ingredient_unit'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO ingredient(name, unit, cat) VALUES('".$ingredient_name."', '".$ingredient_unit."', ".$ingredient_cat.")")or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Does someone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: your code use a password, your error message says that you didn't. did you post the correct code to replicate this problem?

Comment: how are you writing insert query and select query? Can you post that too?

Comment: Yes, it would be good to see the actual code that fails, please.

Comment: You're using the obsolete `mysql_query` to do your insert, which could never work with your `mysqli`-based connection, even if you were trying to use it, which you're not... Also, you're wide open to SQL injection, and should switch to using parameterised queries once you get the connection working.

Comment: also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing `PDO` with `procedural way`...

Replace your `mysql_query(` with `$conn->query(`

Comment: This works, thank you!

Comment: Great, so please accept the answer and use PDO prepared statements to prevent SQL Injections: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496